# ¿Cómo actualizo datos de una bd en java?

Tags: java

mi inconveniente es que no se como actualizar un dato varchar en la bd SQLiteadmin,
mi bd es asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el formVendiTotal esta como varchar

asi traje el numero el programa

```
       conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    try {
     ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM contador");
     while (resultado.next()) {
     int counterID = resultado.getInt("formVendiTotal");System.out.println(counterID);
      txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(counterID));
      FormulariosVendidosTotal=FormulariosVendidosTotal+counterID;
      
      
    };
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

y ahora quiero actualizarlo con un UPDATE pero no se como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolví

```
     String strSentenciaInser = String.format("UPDATE contador SET formVendiTotal='%s'",oPersonas.getMatriTotal());
     objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInser);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para explicar brevemente el funcionamiento del código, en base a [answer]. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.